# How to refer to a local Dockerfile.build file in Jenkinsfile in Scripted Pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

How to convert declarative pipeline as below to scripted pipeline?
I have this syntax for declarative pipeline and I would like to use the dockerfile in my jenkinsfile which is in scripted (node () ) pipeline.

```
pipeline {
    agent { dockerfile true }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
                sh 'svn --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
node {
checkout scm

def customImage = docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}")

customImage.inside {
    sh 'node —-version'
    sh 'svn --version'
  }
}
```

The build() method builds the Dockerfile in the current directory by default. This can be overridden by providing a directory path containing a Dockerfile as the second argument of the build() method, for example:

```
node {
checkout scm
def customImage = docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}", "./dockerfiles/test") 

customImage.inside {
    sh 'node —-version'
    sh 'svn --version'
}
}
```